# What is the greatest inaccuracy in a range of floats?

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

Given two float values (`fLow` and `fHigh`), how could you calculate the greatest or maximum stride/gap between the two successive values?

For example:

In the range `16777217f` to `20000000f` the answer would be `2`, as values are effectively rounded to the nearest two.

Generalizing this to an arbitrary range has got me scratching my head - any suggestions?

cheers,

This should be language neutral, but I'm using C# (which conforms to IEEE-754 for this, I think).

Comment: How did you arrive at the `2` for this specific range?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be 2^ExpMax?

Comment: Cole is right as long as you don't have to deal with subnormals.  @user2152466, how much do you know about floating point numbers, and what ranges will you be interested in?  Do you need to be able to do this for absolutely anything that fits into a float?

Comment: I know the definition in terms of exponent, mantissa, subnormals but don't have a great working intuition - I suspect I can get away without subnormals in practice. So guess it comes to reinterpret_casting to a long and bit manipulation to get the exponent out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is in C. It requires some IEEE 754 behavior, for rounding and such. For IEEE 754 64-bit binary (`double`), `SmallestPositive` is 2<sup>-1074</sup>, approximately 4.9406564584124654417656879286822137236505980261e-324, and DBL_EPSILON is 2<sup>-52</sup>, 2.220446049250313080847263336181640625e-16. For 32-bit binary (`float`), change `DBL` to `FLT` and `double` to `float` wherever they appear (and `fabs` to `fabsf` and `fmax` to `fmaxf`, although it should work without these changes). Then `SmallestPositive` is 2<sup>-149</sup>, approximately 1.401298464324817070923729583289916131280261941876515771757068283889791e-45, and FLT_EPSILON is 2<sup>-23</sup>, 1.1920928955078125e-07.

For an interval between two values, the greatest step size is of course the step size at the endpoint with larger magnitude. (If that endpoint is exactly a power of two, the step size from that point to the next does not appear in the interval itself, so that would be a special case.)

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

/*  Return the ULP of q.

    This was inspired by Algorithm 3.5 in Siegfried M. Rump, Takeshi Ogita, and
    Shin'ichi Oishi, "Accurate Floating-Point Summation", _Technical Report
    05.12_, Faculty for Information and Communication Sciences, Hamburg
    University of Technology, November 13, 2005.
*/
double ULP(double q)
{
    // SmallestPositive is the smallest positive floating-point number.
    static const double SmallestPositive = DBL_EPSILON * DBL_MIN;

    /*  Scale is .75 ULP, so multiplying it by any significand in [1, 2) yields
        something in [.75 ULP, 1.5 ULP) (even with rounding).
    */
    static const double Scale = 0.75 * DBL_EPSILON;

    q = fabs(q);

    return fmax(SmallestPositive, q - (q - q * Scale));
}
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't realize this concept was so mainstream - googling ULP also got me to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp%28double%29 - looks like there isn't a C# built-in but have enough to go on now I think, thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Well, machine accuracy is, as the name indicates, really something that might in general depend on the machine and even on the compiler. So, to be really sure you will typically have to write a program that actually tests what is going on.

However, I suspect that you are really looking for some handy formulas that you can use to *approximate* the maximum distance in a given interval. The Wikipedia article on [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) gives a really nice overview over this topic and I'm mostly quoting from this source in the following.

Let `s` be the machine epsilon of your floating point representation (i.e., about 2^(-24) in the case of standard floats), then the maximum spacing between a **normalised** number `x` and its neighbors is `2*s*|x|`. The word *normalised* is really crucial here and I will not even try to consider the situation for de-normalised numbers because this is where things get really nasty...

That is, in your particular case the maximum spacing `h` in the interval you propose is given by `h = 2*s*max(|fLow|, |fHigh|)`.